# R Function Too Slow With a Reactive Directory

Tags: r, shiny

I have a drop-down menu to select a state as follows:

```
 state_variable<-  reactive({
    return (input$states)})
```

Whatever state the user selects, the state_variable will then be assigned that name. Next, I want to use that string value in the following code:

```
data1 <- eventReactive(input$start,{

    wb<<-loadWorkbook(paste(as.vector(state_variable()), "2015", ".xlsx", sep=""))
**`...#more code is in here but that's not applicable`**
```

I have excel files for every state (ex: NJ2015, AL2015).

**I noticed in my troubleshooting that it takes incredibly long for the workbook to be made. Is there any way I can make the loadWorkbook function faster while having it still do its job?**

Comment: How long does it take to open one of the workbooks in Excel? Is it still long when you open one explicitly in a script (i..e not Shiny)? 

Without a full reproducible example it's hard to tell, but the package `profvis` can help optimize Shiny apps.

Comment: @MarcusA. thank you! I tried but I get the following error: 

profvis: code exited with error:
App dir must contain either app.R or server.R.

Not sure why...